# jsf2/glassfish3 security

Tags: jsf-2, security, glassfish-3

Really big problems.  Homework assignment again.  I've pretty much given up on trying to get it to work, there isn't enough time anymore for it.  I've tried reading through everything on security on docs.oracle, everything on security on NetBeans, everything provided with the class (textbook doesn't cover any of this, so  can't blame it on an outdated book this time) and a bunch of tutorials through google and alot of questions on here.  I can't get it to work.

I'm not looking for an answer to the homework, more of what I need to look at and things to double-check that I might be overlooking....

The application should allow users in two different groups to login.  Admin users have access to everything while User users have access to only /user/*.  We aren't restricted to strictly programmatic security and we aren't restricted to a specific declarative security.  We have to create a servlet to control page flow (as much as I mentioned it to the instructor that JSF comes with a controller and page flow can be controlled through the framework already didn't affect his decision any.)  If someone not currently logged in tries to access one of the protected areas, they should be prompted to login/redirected to the login page/whatever needs to happen to login based on our security implementation.  If a logged in User user tries to access the admin area, they should prompted they aren't Admin, no details on if they should just be returned to where they were, logged out or prompted to login as an Admin.  The only requirement is we can't use a database to store usernames and passwords.

So I went with setting up two users in the file realm, one as User, one as Admin.  I tried setting it up for basic authentication, it doesn't prompt for login when the user runs the page.  I tried creating a custom login/login error pages and form authentication, it wouldn't display my login form when the user ran the page.  So far, the only thing I've been able to do is have the Login page as the welcome file and call the servlet on form submission and it uses request.login(username, password) and logs the user in if they are found in the realm and everything matches.  I can then check the role and set things in the user's bean and forward them to the proper start page based on the assigned role.  But if I run it and navigate to another page without entering data into the form and submitting it to login, the pages display.  If I login as the User role and navigate to one of the admin area pages, it lets me.  I've set up security constraints for the urls, I've used filters from examples I've seen on here for the different urls, and they don't get called.

There is probably something simple I am missing, and coming into this class not knowing html and stuff other than java is probably the biggest problem, and I honestly don't know how I'm borderline A in this class....
There is more to the project than this, but the rest isn't something I see myself having a problem with, but I've been hung up on the security part of this for most of the week and haven't even started on it.

web.xml

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Project2.Controller</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>AdminConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>Admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>UserConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>user</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>User</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    </web-app>
```

login.xhtml

```
    <f:view>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
                <title>JSP Page</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1><h:outputText value="Welcome!  Choose an action below."/></h1>

                <form method="Post" action="Controller">
                    <h:inputText id="userName" value=""/>
                    <h:inputSecret id="password" value=""/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Login" type="submit"/>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    </f:view>
```

Comment: So far what you did looks good. But looks something wrong here "But if I run it and navigate to another page without entering data into the form and submitting it to login, the pages display". Can you post the code for your web.xml and the login page?

Comment: @Ravi So, in pasting the code in here and formatting it, I noticed a few things that weren't showing up before or things I thought I removed.  It was setup to load index.html as the welcome file, I thought I had Login.jsp set, and login was set to FORM.  So it was displaying the login page after all.  In removing the tags for FORM as the login type, running it displays the pop-up login box, for some reason I couldn't get that to display earlier, either.  It still lets me bypass the constraints for the two urls, though, logged in or not.  Maybe something with my Glassfish server?

Comment: Seriously starting to wonder if I was making changes in the wrong web.xml at times.  But Glassfish was acting strange, also.  It kept emptying the realm of users or doubling the groups.

Answer (score 0):

So based on what you have your goal seems to achieve container based authentication and authorization. So in addition to what you have you also need to add login configuration to your Deployment Descriptor like this:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>yourRealmName</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

The above configuration specifies the login page where the user types in the username and password and the error page to which it is redirected if the authentication fails.

And in your login.xhtml you need to specify to POST the form to j_security_check like this:

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="j_username" />
  <input type="secret" name="j_password" />
  ...
</form>
```

Alternatively to container based authentication, you can also do programmatic authentication where upon submitting the form. The user role is checked and the desired action outcome is returned. I think you don't need that controller anymore.

More details on this see the Java EE 6 documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxce.html)

Comment: The controller is required as part of the assignment.  It has been mentioned numerous times the assignments we've been given don't need it.  I dropped login-config info because I thought I had removed it and had the welcome file as Login.jsp, but it seems I made those changes on the web.xml file for the first attempt at this.

Comment: I lost count how many times I've read through the documentation this week.  With FORM, does it have to use that exact form?  I've been able to get request.login() to work in my controller with my Login.jsp.  After that, I've been lost.  I have the controller setting the username and role to a bean to call later, but I'm sure there are other ways around it.  This is probably more me not really knowing html than anything else.

Comment: Changed the Login.jsp to Login.xhtml, for some reason with Login.jsp, it doens't want to load anymore, the xhtml just shows a blank page.

Comment: Oh I mean to change your login.jsp to have form action as j_security_check

Comment: So I've pretty much given up one trying to use the web container security, going more programmatic.  Working on getting at least the rest of the requirements working for now.  Thanks, though.  I'll still have to come back to this later as I don't see the rest of the homework straying away from this, everything has built on the previous week's homework.  The thing I don't understand is how it'll work randomly with basic authentication, but not form, but I can get it to work programmatically with a form, and neither working method seem to enforce the constraints.

Comment: Basic prompts as soon as you run the project, and the welcome file doens't fit the url patterns of the constraints.  I'm just gonna stick with every page having a form the posts to a servlet and displays a value from a bean method that checks if the user has been logged in and if they're in the right role.

Comment: Okay, do one thing here is the link on how to run the examples included in Java SDK.[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html#bncby). You can download the example [here](http://java.net/downloads/javaeetutorial/javaeetutorial6.zip). Just  follow the instructions and run the sample on your localhost and see where you are missing.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually one of the first things I tried.  The only difference between my requirements and what that does is I have two different collections for constraints and two roles.  I've used the GUI editor for the security that NetBeans provides and using Basic, it only prompts once and on "/*" instead of "/user/*" and "/admin/*"  If I clean and build and deploy and manually go to any of the pages in under the "protected" urls, it just lets me in, doesn't prompt and ignores roles.  But with a custom form and using a servlet and calling request.login, I can see the roles.

Comment: I have more time to sort through this.  It's a new week, so new homework.  We're replacing the text file utilized elsewhere as a catalog with a database, security requirements remain the same.